# PHP Email content arriving as attachment

Tags: php

I have this piece of PHP code, although it works, but the problem is that the email message content is sent as an attachment along with the intended attachment which means that when the email arrives, the body is blank but there's two attachments. One is the intended attachment and the other is the email content that is supposed to be displayed in the the email. Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Here's the full source code:

```
<?php
require('fpdf/fpdf.php');
include('./config.php');

$pdf = new FPDF('P', 'pt', 'Letter');
$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(true, $margin);

$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('arial','',12);

   if(isset($_POST['accept'])){
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $to = 'me@somewhere.com';
    $subject = urldecode($_POST['subject']);
    $message = urldecode($_POST['message']);

    $data = '';

    $result = mysql_query("select * from applications where id = $id");
    $row = $data_array = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

    $data .= "Name: " . $row['name'] . " \n\n";
    $data .= "Surname: " . $row['surname'] . "\n\n";    
    $data .= "Age: ". $row['age'] . "\n\n";
    $data .= "Dob: ". $row['dob'] . "\n\n"; 
    $data .= "Height: ". $row['height'] . "\n\n";
    $data .= "Add1 : ".$row['address1'] . "\n\n";   
    $data .= "Add2:  ".$row['address2'] . "\n\n";   
    $data .= "Add3: ".$row['address3'] . "\n\n";
    $data .= "Postcode: ".$row['postcode'] . "\n\n";            
    $data .= "Town:  ".$row['town'] . "\n\n";   
    $data .= "County: ". $row['county']. "\n\n";    
    $pdf->SetX(140);

    $pdf->Ln(2);

    $pdf->MultiCell(0, 15, $data);

    $from     = "me@mydomain.com"; 

    $separator = md5(time());

    $eol = PHP_EOL;

    // attachment name
    $filename = "form.pdf";

    // encode data (puts attachment in proper format)
    $pdfdoc = $pdf->Output("", "S");
    $attachment = chunk_split(base64_encode($pdfdoc));

    // main header
    $headers  = "From: ".$from.$eol;
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0".$eol; 
    $headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"".$separator."\"";

    $body = "--".$separator.$eol;
    $body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit".$eol.$eol;

    // message
    $body .= "--".$separator.$eol;
    $body .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"".$eol;
    $body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit".$eol.$eol;
    $body .= $message.$eol;

    // attachment
    $body .= "--".$separator.$eol;
    $body .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"".$filename."\"".$eol; 
    $body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64".$eol;
    $body .= "Content-Disposition: attachment".$eol.$eol;
    $body .= $attachment.$eol;
    $body .= "--".$separator."--";

    // send message
    if(mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers)){

                echo "<b>Email successfully sent</b>";
        }
    else{
         echo "Your message could not be sent.";
      }
}

?>
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: If you're not confident enough to implement sending emails manually properly and/or debug it - why don't you use libraries that do that well for you? Like phpmailer

Comment: I second @zerkms, you're better off just using a library to do your sending, unless you're one of those who has to control it directly. [PHPMailer](http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpmailer/)

Comment: phpmailer is the easiest way to send mail with php. I use it all the time and think its much simpler than doing it manually.

Answer (score 1):

I actually have some experience with single-handedly writing this kind of thing from scratch. After years of maintaining a home-brewed PHP e-mail builder, my advice is that you shouldn't. It **certainly** takes less time and resources to research and find the most well-supported, mainstream solution today (whenever today is) than to write your own (and to pay for all the inherent bugs with your time and/or resources).

Comment: Oh hell, I have *experience* here too; seriously, unless you just have to know how the sausage is made, *outsource* the sausage making. `sendmail` famously claimed *there's sharp edges here*. Take care in that.

Comment: @Gutza- thanks for the comment. I will look at something else next time but just wanted to get this working for now. I appreciate your comment.

Comment: @HelenNeely you don't get it. This won't work. For instance your $separator is uncertain. You need a lot of research on how various MUAs interpret your various hardcoded MIME statements. And this is just based on a superficial reading -- you're in a world of pain.